# Handle AWS SQS failure scenario?

Tags: amazon-sqs

I understand AWS SQS is high reliability, but still there are still chance that network can be disconnected from our server to the AWS datacenter from time to time.

Are there any way tool to prevent this kind of error, e.g. by caching the request locally and resend if network is available again?

Comment: I suspect this question falls under the category of "too broad."  It depends on what you are using SQS for, and what resources are available in your local DC, like a database or ActiveMQ or any kind of something where messages could go.  In some cases, the design assumption would be that if SQS isn't available, you would deliberately return an error to your own caller because you can't fulfill their request.  You could also use SNS in a different AWS region and let it be responsible for delivering the message back to your target SQS queue.

Comment: ...you could conceivably even write a local proxy that spoofs SQS to your application, but with a solution like that, you run a signifcant risk of the failure of your solution being more likely than the problem it was created to solve.  (If you can't tell, I'm currently in the middle of re-reading [*Normal Accidents: Living with High Risk Technologies*](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00CHRINUI)).

Answer (score 1):

The AWS SDK has [built-in retries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#setRetryPolicy-com.amazonaws.retry.RetryPolicy-) to handle transient errors - you can configure the retry policy based on your needs.  This should handle the most common types of network errors dealing with AWS.

If AWS service you depend on is down for longer than retry policy will handle, then you need to decide how to handle that - you could fallback to other AWS region(s) (very unlikely the service is down in multiple regions), or emit failures to your service callers, or cache locally, drop the requests, or something else entirely.

Handling failure cases is highly variable, and depends on the use case and needs of the system - there's definitely no "one right way". As a note, I've used each of the above failure mode suggestions I made on different systems I've built that depend on AWS.